# Re-set up iMessages?

Tags: macos

I need help re-setting up iMessages.  I think I entered the wrong ID because now I can't get in.  It keeps telling me the Id or password is wrong, but I can't enter a new ID, just a new password.  How to re-set it up Please??  Thank you so much

Comment: Is this for Mac or iPhone? You tagged it as both, but the process is different on each platform.

Comment: It's for my mac.  Now I got passed that message but still doesn't work.  Now I keep getting this message:  Non-secure Jabber Login:  Your user name (queenee44) and password will be sent in a way that is not secure.  Do you still wish to connect to xmpp.l.google.com? It keeps popping up.  I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: While the Messages app is active...

In the top left corner of your screen, click the bold **Messages**, then "Preferences", then the "Accounts" tab.

On the iMessage account, hit the "Sign Out" button. Then it will allow you to enter in your password as well as Apple ID again.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I don't know what happened but I get:  Non-secure Jabber login - Your user name (queenee44) and password will be sent in a way that is not secure.  Do you still wish to connect to xmpp.l.google.com?

Comment: @tewks I wouldn't do that. It's probably fine, but if you're on a public Wi-Fi network (one in a coffee shop, Wal-Mart, restaurant, etc.), wait until you get home or have access to secure Wi-Fi at a family member or friend's house, as the message is saying that your account credentials could be compromised by being sent over an insecure network.

Comment: Ok, I did the above and it still isn't working.  When it used to work, I had messages on there, now there is no history of those.  It wiped it out.  When I go on my phone under Settings > Messages > Send and Receive - it says 6 addresses and all are checked and black but my phone number is grayed out (but still checked).  How do I fix this?  I'm going crazy.  Thank you so much.  I'm not on a public wifi.

Comment: Thank you everyone, One of your answers worked!!  Thank you so much!